# 2 forms communicate c#

Tags: c#, windows

Hi i am having 2 forms on a application, and want to use one form to set a label in a an other form, i looked around for an answer, but i didn't got it working. code:

form 1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void uit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
            frm.Show();
        }

        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return uit.Text; }
            set { uit.Text = value; }
        }

    }
```

form 2:

> ```
> public partial class Form2 : Form
> {
>     private Form1 mainForm = null;
>     public Form2(Form callingForm)
>     {
>         mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>     private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         txtmessage.Text = this.mainForm.LabelText;
>     }
>     public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         this.mainForm.LabelText = txtmessage.Text;
>     }
> }
> ```

could someone explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: That looks like it should work - what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Which bit exactly doesn't work? I'm assuming you've tried stepping through it and examining the objects as you go?

Comment: May be this is a problem: 
...
txtmessage.Text = this.mainForm.LabelText;
...
this.mainForm.LabelText = txtmessage.Text;
...

Comment: Should work. Does it work in one way or in none? What does the debugger say when you put a breakpoint  in `Form2_Load` or `button1_Click` about the values in Form2-Label and Form1-Label?

Comment: @Blogbeard I don't know what's going wrong, when i click uit Form2 opens, but when i edit txtmessage, and click button1, the text at uit doesn't change 
@Ira Rainet, i don't know what you exactely mean @iburlakov, first the content of uit needs to be loaded in txtmessage

Comment: okey that's quite weird, i worked on it, and it didn't work also, so i copied the code back, and now it doesn't even open form2 when i click uit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just built it and it works fine. I'm assuming that you've got the events hooked up?

Comment: thanks, i have builded it from scratch, and i said at button1_click this.txtmessage.Text and now it works